# Delete query fields from model instance

Tags: python, sql-server, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a SAP Business One model called OHEM in my Django project but this ERP allow the custom fields creation for each company.

Actually I have an admin for one of this company and the other would like to use them but when run the code in the company "B" database I have the next warning:

> The name of column 'U_INT_EMPLOYEE_CODE' don't exists. (207)

The company "A" have a lot of user fields and the company "B" have another user different fields for the same model and want to use the same code for both

### Shared model

```py
class Ohem(models.Model):
    empid = models.IntegerField(db_column='empID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    lastname = models.CharField(db_column='lastName', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    firstname = models.CharField(db_column='firstName', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    middlename = models.CharField(db_column='middleName', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
    jobtitle = models.CharField(db_column='jobTitle', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    type = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    dept = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    branch = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    # Company A fields
    u_int_cod_empleado = models.IntegerField(db_column='U_INT_COD_EMPLEADO', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    u_hbt_contrasena = models.CharField(db_column='U_HBT_Contrasena', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    u_hbt_cardcode = models.CharField(db_column='U_HBT_CardCode', max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    u_fechactualisap = models.DateTimeField(db_column='U_FechActualiSAP', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    u_fechactualimovil = models.DateTimeField(db_column='U_FechActualiMovil', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.}

    # Company B fields
    u_hbt_cardcode = models.CharField(db_column='U_HBT_CardCode', max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    u_internalusercode = models.DateTimeField(db_column='U_INTUSER_COD', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
```

I want delete this fields before SQL executes, But Model._meta.fields are ImmutableList and Model._meta.concrete_fields too

Comment: Could you use inheritance? Maybe have class Ohem contain the common fields, then derive `A` & `B` from `Ohem`? Might be simpler than trying to hack the _meta fields.

Comment: It may be but the problem comes when the ability to add more companies and have to duplicate views, serializers an "n" times becomes complex